# Tree Array to sitemap

Tags: c#, php, c++, arrays

I have two homework problems for school, and i have looked over them several times and didn't get it

I have this array

Array[10][10][10]

```
id  parent  value
1   0       X
2   1       Y
3   1       Z
4   3       A
5   2       B
6   5       C
7   3       D
8   9       E
9   4       F
10  2       G
```

What i want is to generate a sitemap based on parent column.

```
Example
1 must be at the root
2 and 3 must be childs of 1
10 and 5 must be childs of 2
... and so on.
```

I would like if i could generate an .xml like

```
<object id="1" value="X">
    <object id="2" value="Y">
        <object id="10" value="G">
        </object>
        <object id="5" value="B">
        </object>

        ... and so on ...

    </object>
</object>
```

and an array

```
array(
    id = > 1
    array
);
```

i don't look how it might actually look, maybe something like this

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    42    => 24,
    "multi" => array(
         "dimensional" => array(
             "array" => "foo"
         )
    )
);
```

and the second problem i will post it later. I'm using PHP for this, but C++ and C# would work as well, because the algorithm is important.  Any help would be apreciated, because i'm very curious about this!

Comment: You don't need anything complicated for this. A simple single-dimension of structs with parent and value should be all that is required. You're domain has the benefit of having the id's being contiguous and starting at one, so ar[n-1] where n is the id will lead you to the node itself for all n > 0. hope that made sense.

Comment: Quick on .. is your array in this format `array("id"=>1,"parent"=>0,"value"=>"X")`

Comment: hey thanks, but right now i'm working on the code, i think i need to use classes and objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your array looks like this

```
$list = array();
$list[] = array("id" => 1,"parent" => 0,"value" => "X");
$list[] = array("id" => 2,"parent" => 1,"value" => "Y");
$list[] = array("id" => 3,"parent" => 1,"value" => "Z");
$list[] = array("id" => 4,"parent" => 3,"value" => "A");
$list[] = array("id" => 5,"parent" => 2,"value" => "B");
$list[] = array("id" => 6,"parent" => 5,"value" => "C");
$list[] = array("id" => 7,"parent" => 3,"value" => "D");
$list[] = array("id" => 8,"parent" => 9,"value" => "E");
$list[] = array("id" => 9,"parent" => 4,"value" => "F");
$list[] = array("id" => 10,"parent" => 2,"value" => "G");
```

You can try

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<data />");
startBuild($list, $xml);
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data> <object id="1" value="X">
    <object id="2" value="Y">
        <object id="5" value="B">
            <object id="6" value="C" />
        </object>
        <object id="10" value="G" />
    </object>
    <object id="3" value="Z">
        <object id="4" value="A">
            <object id="9" value="F">
                <object id="8" value="E" />
            </object>
        </object>
        <object id="7" value="D" />
    </object>
</object> 
</data>
```

Function Used

```
function startBuild(array $array, SimpleXMLElement $xml, $no = 0) {
    $child = hasChildren($array, $no);
    if (empty($child))
        return "";

    foreach ( $child as $value ) {
        $xChild = $xml->addChild("object");
        $xChild->addAttribute("id", $value['id']);
        $xChild->addAttribute("value", $value['value']);
        startBuild($array, $xChild, $value['id']);
    }
    return true;
}

function hasChildren($array, $id) {
    return array_filter($array, function ($var) use($id) {
        return $var['parent'] == $id;
    });
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, but i'm still trying to understand it 100%, but can you look over my code http://codepad.org/jtEj6c2S i'm using classes and objects, can you help me with this?

Comment: You code does not say mush .. you are just outputting  id, parent and value

Comment: i don't have a clear idea how to make it, basically i want to use objects (my teacher want this) http://codepad.org/Q8QvKARJ, what should i do next? And i will take your response as an answer because it's a good response, but can you help me do it my way also ? thank you :D

Comment: That is very easy. . I can even make it work with object and array. .. What do i think

Comment: i don't know what to do next, i'm getting into classes and objects, this is the propose of the homework, even though your example works perfectly :D

Comment: You array is wrong .. it must stat with 1 like your example if not it would become infinite loop ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17832/discussion-between-row-minds-and-baba)

Comment: you couldn't make it run smoother than that! :D thank you very much, i will study this more till i understand it like 100%